# How to install nltk stopwords packages manually

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

example_sent = "This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration."

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_sent)

filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]

filtered_sentence = []

for w in word_tokens:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)


print(word_tokens)
print(filtered_sentence)
```

But when running the code, I am getting this error:

```
Resource stopwords not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource
```

If I download the `NLTK Downloader`, I am getting the below error:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading popular: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An
[nltk_data]     existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
[nltk_data]     host>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 8):

Does this work?

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Read the below links and it can be solved:

https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues/791
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060070/ConnectionResetError-WinError-An-existing-connecti
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/193